# Access Dlookup where relationship already exists

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have a fact table with a primary key `Ending Item Code` and a foreign key `Starting Item Code`. The primary key is *left joined* to a dim table *Item Information Table* where the foreign key could be as well. I want to get a column *Dlookup'd* over instead of creating another query to join to my fact table to but I don't think my syntax is correct and I can't find any information on people using the *Dlookup* like this. What am I doing wrong?

**Specific DLOOKUP code:**

```
DLOOKUP(" [Descripition] "," [DIM TABLE] ", " FT.[Starting Item Code] = DT.[Item Code] ") AS [Start Item Description]
```

**Fact Table:**

```
Starting Item Code | Ending Item Code
_____________________________________
1050                 1051
```

**Dim Table:**

```
Item Code | Description
_______________________
1050        Chum
1051        Krabby Paddies
```

**SQL Code:**

```
SELECT

FT.Starting Item Code,
FT.Ending Item Code,
DT.Description AS [Ending Item Description],

DLOOKUP(" [Descripition] "," [DIM TABLE] ", " FT.[Starting Item Code] = DT.[Item Code] ") AS [Start Item Description]

FROM [Fact Table] AS FT

LEFT JOIN [Dim Table] AS DT
ON FT.[Ending Item Code] = DT.[Item Code]
```

**The query result I want:**

```
Starting Item Code | Starting Item Description | Ending Item Code | Ending Item Description
____________________________________________________________________________________________
1050                 Chum                        1051               Krabby Paddies
```